# Android pass parameters to TimerTask extends class

Tags: android, android-task

in my application i need to pass parameters to TimerTask for use `Context`. but i can not do it. in this below code `GetSMSThread` class is `subclass` and that need to get parameters from main class.

```
Timer smsThread = new Timer();
GetSMSThread getSMSThread = new GetSMSThread();
smsThread.scheduleAtFixedRate(getSMSThread, 0, 100000);
```

`GetSMSThread` subClass:

```
public class GetSMSThread extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {

    }
}
```

Comment: You can declare you TimerTask class itself in MainClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There two ways to resolve your issue

- Declare your `GetSMSThread` it self in `MainClass` so no need to send params in `Constructor`
- Another way is to send parameters in `Constructors`

**Option 1 :**

```
public class MainClass extends Activity {

    private String myString = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // .... your code
        Timer smsThread = new Timer();
        GetSMSThread getSMSThread = new GetSMSThread();
        smsThread.scheduleAtFixedRate(getSMSThread, 0, 100000);
        myString = "assigning some value";
    }

    public class GetSMSThread extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            myString = "manipulating Values";
        }
    }

}
```

**Option 2 :**

```
public class MainClass extends Activity {

    private String myString = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // .... your code
        myString = "assigning some value";
        Timer smsThread = new Timer();
        GetSMSThread getSMSThread = new GetSMSThread(myString);
        smsThread.scheduleAtFixedRate(getSMSThread, 0, 100000);
    }

}
```

**GetSMSThread :**

```
public class GetSMSThread extends TimerTask {

    private String myString = "";

    public GetSMSThread(String mString) {
        myString = mString;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        myString = "manipulating Values";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Timer smsThread = new Timer();
    GetSMSThread getSMSThread = new GetSMSThread("data");
    smsThread.scheduleAtFixedRate(getSMSThread, 0, 100000);
    GetSMSThread subClass:

    public class GetSMSThread extends TimerTask {

     String data;
    GetSMSThread(String data){

     this.data = data;

    }
        @Override
        public void run() {
              //use data here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a context object to a class through a constructor.

```
public class GetSMSThread extends TimerTask {
Context context;
public GetSMSThread (Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public void run() {
   //make sure you dont use the context in a background thread
}
}
```

You can instantiate the **GetSMSThread ** class and pass a valid context to it:

```
GetSMSThread  myThread = new GetSMSThread(myContext);
//start your timer
```